# Unable to delete program

Tags: windows, installation

Delete program button is gray and can't click it. I try to install the program (Pro Tools first) but it says that it cannot be installed because another version is already installed on the computer, but the files are nowhere to be found. It also guides to go to apps and remove the software before installing this one.

Comment: Here is a picture of what the button looks like http://prntscr.com/mitbxn. Poista asennus is finnish and it means remove installation.

Comment: Please upload a translated copy of the image to imgur using the upload image functionality.  A link to the screenshot is fine.

Answer (score 0):

(please ignore previous answer. I later noticed that it is not allowing you to install.)

Try free tool Revo uninstaller, whether the program is appearing in its Programs list.

If it is, try uninstalling from there, it will also scan registry and disks and will remove any remains of the program.

If it is not appearing in Revo uninstaller, it is already removed and due to some bug, its entry is appearing in Windows uninstaller. Normally, in such cases, Windows asks that it could not find program to uninstall, so should it remove the program name from this list. say Yes and it will get removed.

You are seeing in Windows 10 Settings - Apps. Also go to good old Windows 8 style Control Panel - Programs and Features, whether it is appearing there.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: It worked with Revo uninstaller. Thank you very much!